# $T$-equivariant resolution of coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $X := \{x_1x_2= 0\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ and let $\mathcal{F} := \mathcal{O}_0$ where $0\in X$ is the origin. Let $T = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} t_1 & 0 \\ 0 & t_2\end{pmatrix}\right\}\subset \operatorname{GL}_2$ act on $X$ diagonally.

What is the minimal $T$-equivariant resolution of $\mathcal{F}$?

Answer (score 2):

The resolution has the form
$$
\dots \to
\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} 
\stackrel{\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)}\longrightarrow
\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} 
\stackrel{\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_1\end{smallmatrix}\right)}\longrightarrow
\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} 
\stackrel{\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x_1 & x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)}\longrightarrow
\mathcal{O} \longrightarrow
\mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 
0.
$$
It is obvious that it has a $T$-equivariant structure.

Comment: Thanks. How do you arrive at this resolution?

Comment: And how do you arrive at $2*2 = 4$? By computing...